# How to disable “allow the computer to turn off this device to save power” using C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, usb, setupapi

I my C++ application, I need to disable this option for the hubs that I can find in "Device Manager/Universal Serial Bus controllers".

I have iterated in these hubs using SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo and SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId, but after that I don't now what to do, maybe it's not the best way, I don't know.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 10.

Someone can help me?

Grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to use the `WinUsb_SetPowerPolicy` function. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winusb/nf-winusb-winusb_setpowerpolicy) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

The class `CIM_USBDevice : CIM_LogicalDevice` might be able to help you with your problem.
[CIM_USBDevice class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/cim-usbdevice)